# AR.js framework for real time location tracking

Tags: javascript, three.js, augmented-reality, ar.js

Can  AR.js web framework be used to build a Augmented Reality web application that guides user to navigate from the current location to given destination (lat,long)

I want to make it run on available chrome/safari web browser available on android/apple devices. Can you please point to sample / more info on the same

Answer (score 0):

No, not really. AR.js only offers marker based AR; meaning that you show a specific image to the webcam, AR.js recognizes it and uses it to place objects relative to the marker.

Answer (score 0):

Update:

AR.js now supports location based AR. [AR.js v2.0.0 with location based AR](https://github.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js/#arjs-v200-is-out)

AR.js can now be used with its default Marker Based feature, with Location Based or both combined.